# Indicator function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm looking for an indicator function in R, i.e. a function that returns a 1, if the value of an element in a vector is greater than 0 and returns zero, if the value of an element in a vector is less than 0.

I need to use this function on all elements in a vector returning a new vector with only zeros and ones.

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with the normal `>` operator?

Comment: `as.numeric(x>0)` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i am able to understand you correctly then you want to make changes into entire data frame,assuming of which i can suggest you to use apply like below, where df is your data frame.

```
apply(df,2,function(x)ifelse((x>0),1,0))
```

You can also use if its for only one vector something like below:

```
x <- c(-2,3,1,0)
y <- ifelse(x>0,1,0)
print(y)
[1] 0 1 1 0 #Output
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

There are a variety of ways, the minimal keystroke one:

```
  Ivec <- 0+(vec>0)
```

Saves a couple of keystrokes over: `as.numeric(vec>0)`. I would guess the `ifelse(x>0,1,0)`-approach would be somewhat slower if applied to a large vector or if used in simulations. Could also use:

```
 Ivec <- 1*(vec>0)
```

Comment: For the first one, are parentheses needed?

Comment: It is if you want the result to be numeric, which is what was requested. You could have easily checked this yourself with `vec=2; 0+vec>0`

Answer (score 3):

The `I` function in R, called the *Inhibit Interpretation/Conversion of Objects function*, can be used for this purpose. For instance, the line below returns the values for the function I(x < 4) where X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}:

```
> I(0:5 < 4)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

In R `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be treated as 1 and 0s, but if you insist on your output being precisely those numbers, just wrap your `I` function into `as.numeric`.

Comment: Why have you used the Asis function...not using it returns the same object (`0:5 < 4`). When you do use it the returned object is now of class 'AsIs' (which may produce unexpected downstream consequences)

Answer (score -1):

There is also an built-in indicator function in R

> Indicator(x,min,max)

-Inf and Inf are still the valid values.

Comment: This code doesn't work on base R (version 3.6). Perhaps you found this function in a package?