# Writing an Indicator function in R

Tags: r, function, indicator

I am trying to create an indictor variable, Z, in R, i.e If I have some event A, I want Z to give a result of 1 if A is true and 0 if A is false. 
I have tried this:

```
Z=0
if(A==(d>=5 && d<=10))
  {
    Z=1
  }
  else
  {
    Z=0
  }
```

But this doesn't work. I was also thinking i could try to write a separate function called indicator:

```
indicator = function()
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indikator function in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096514/indikator-function-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

You could easily write something like this

`indicator<-function(condition) ifelse(condition,1,0)`

`ifelse` can be used on vectors, but it works perfectly fine on single logical values (TRUE or FALSE).

Comment: Thank you, that was a lot of help!

Comment: Also 1*(condition) can do the same thing, and it's shorter (although a bit harder to read).

Answer (score 2):

Booleans `FALSE` / `TRUE` can be coerced to be `0` or `1` and then be multiplied:

```
Indicator<-function(x, min=0, max=Inf)
    { 
        as.numeric(x >= min) * as.numeric(x <= max)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`a <- data.frame(a = -5:5, b = 1:11)
indicator <- function(data) I(data > 0) + 1 - 1
indicator(a)`

`a` can be vector, data frame...

And you can chance the logical in `I` function with your interest.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to define A, just test the condition. 
Also, remember that `&&` and `&` have different uses in R (see [R - boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/r-boolean-operators-and) for more details), so maybe that is part of your problem.

```
if (d>=5 & d<=10)
   {
   Z <- 1
   }
  else
   {
   Z <- 0
   }
```

Or, as suggested in the other answer use `ifelse`:

```
z <- ifelse((d>=5 & d<=10), 1, 0)
```